# Chrome extension: short description in multiple languages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome extension you take care for the short description in the manifest.json itself with the attribut: description!

In the Chrome Appstore you can have a more detailed description in several languages!
But how to localize the short description in the manifest.json for multiple languages?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [internationalization documentation](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html#l10) describes how to have multiple translations for the name field in the manifest. The same method should work for the description field in the manifest.